# I trying to make a discord bot using javascript..but it giving me error

Tags: javascript, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc6Gn.png)

it giving me this error:

```
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'FLAGS')
```

I expect it to run my bot on my discord channel

Comment: The error is telling you that `Intents` is `undefined`.

Comment: Please don't post code images or bugs if possible, copy your code or code error into question with block code format: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The `Intents` property has moved about in the Discord.js API. Use the documentation for the version of discord.js that you have installed. (Most likely you have the current version of discord.js installed and are following an out of date tutorial).

Answer (score -1):

It says that the object `Intents` are `undefined` and doesn't have property `FLAGS`. Please double-check your object, print it with `console.log` see if it actually there.

Comment: "It says that the object Intents doesn't have property FLAGS"  — **Incorrect**. It says that the variable `Intents` has the value `undefined` (and that because it is `undefined` you can't read `FLAGS` from it).